# How function overloading works with double and float

Tags: c++, overloading

I have two overloaded methods

```
double Sum(double n1, double n2)
{
     return n1 + n2;
}

float Sum(float n1, float n2)
{
     return n1 + n2;
}
```

When I call `Sum(5.5, 5.5)`, the method with `double` return type gets called.

My question is why the method with `double` return type is called, and why not the method with `float` return type? How is the compiler deciding which method should be called?

Comment: Since 5.5 is a double literal, the version with doubles is called.

Comment: Its more efficient, if you want to call the other, affix your parameters with f, also you must be assigning the return to a double?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, floating-point literals such as **5.5** have the type `double` in **C++** as default. That's why, when you pass a **double literal** to an overloaded function, it is going to call the version of that function which accepts the double typed parameters.

If you want to override this default behaviour, you need to be using **suffix notations** such as `f` to let the compiler know which type does literal have. As an example, you need to be passing `Sum(5.5f, 5.5f)` instead of `Sum(5.5, 5.5)` to avoid default behaviour.

Comment: You mean to say, if we have to pass float, then we have to explicitly convert the number to float ? right ? @HimanshuAhuja

Comment: You need to be using suffix `f` such as `5.5f` to let the compiler know that it is a float typed literal.

Comment: @WaleedNaveed -- if you want to pass a float you have to pass a float. `5.5` is not a float. `5.5f` is a float, and `static_cast<float>(5.5)` is a float, and after `float f = 5.5;`, `f` is a float.